Automatic Status Update When Another Cell Value Is Updated With Any Date
I have a worksheet where employees log details of applications received. I'm trying to work out a formula that lets the status of the applicant auto-update to caregiver in a target cell, when there's any date input in another cell.
I wrote my formula as this: =IF(D2="date","Caregiver",IF(ISBLANK(D2),"Applicant")).
The only problem here is the word "date" which returns as "FALSE" in the target cell when an actual date is entered in the Hire Date cell and not the word "date". If I input 6/24/2024, the result comes back as "FALSE" in the target cell but if I enter "date" everything works fine.
My goal is to have the target cell change its status to "Caregiver" when I input an actual date.
I know that the problem is how to represent date in the syntax. How can I fix this?
Thanks a lot.
Here's a link to the worksheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1274eFAqzblsq6IGZ8BOWcBa-4wtMei44uiGqC94QsP0/edit#gid=1636885054

the shared sheet has restricted access

Access has been updated now. I tried this formula- =IF(D2="","Applicant","Caregiver") and it worked but the only problem is that succeeding empty cells update with "Applicant" by default. I have tried to add the IF(ISBLANK condition to no avail.

Can you manually add & showcase your ideal expected output bcoz I cant get a clear picture on what the end goal is! As per your explained/provided logic, all blank cells(from Column_D)  will be marked Applicant(in Column_H)?!

@rockinfreakshow I have updated the succeeding cells with the new formula. That's the outcome I want but also with a condition that if Caregiver (Column_B) is without an entry, then status remain empty as well


You may try this in Cell_H2:
=ifs(B2="",,D2="","Applicant",1,"Caregiver")

